# How to save file into possibly new directory?

Tags: c++, file, boost, save, boost-filesystem

So I have some base `boost::filesystem::path Base` I want to create folder if one does not exist and create a binary file from string. Currently I have a function like this:

```
void file_service::save_string_into_file( std::string contents, std::string name )
{
    std::ofstream datFile;
    name = "./basePath/extraPath/" + name;
    datFile.open(name.c_str(), std::ofstream::binary | std::ofstream::trunc | std::ofstream::out    );
    datFile.write(contents.c_str(), contents.length());
    datFile.close();
}
```

It requires from the directories to exist. So I wonder how to update my function to boost.filesystem APIs in order to reach desired functionality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that in order to use the boost::filesystem library, you will need to link against the pre-compiled boost::filesystem static library, and the boost::system static library.

```
#include "boost/filesystem.hpp"

boost::filesystem::path rootPath ( "./basePath/extraPath/" );
boost::system::error_code returnedError;

boost::filesystem::create_directories( rootPath, returnedError );

if ( returnedError )
   //did not successfully create directories
else
   //directories successfully created
```

Answer (score 4):

There's a [`create_directories`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html) convenience function in `boost::filesystem`. It creates directories recursively, so you don't have to traverse the possibly new path yourself.

It's in `<boost/filesystem/convenience.hpp>`.